# I want to show the body text in another div in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to show the body text in another div in CKEditor. I used the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$('#rerg').empty();
$("body#contentfsf").clone().appendTo("#rerg");
},1000);
});
```

and

```
config.bodyId = 'contentfsf';
```

Preview should be in,

```
<div id="rerg">

</div>
```

It does not work.
Please provide me with a solution or with any other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Am not too used to jquery, but with javascript this should do :

document.getElementById("rerg").innerHTML = valueToWrite;

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("keyup", "#contentfsf", function () {
    $("#rerg).html($(this).val());
});
```

This will copy the content from the editor to the div.

You dont need:

```
setInterval function;
```

*not tested